# What is the most Unix-y way to handle stdout for a backup command that might fail?

Tags: shell, process, exit

I am writing a utility/script (in Python, as it happens) to run on Linux, which backs up data from a remote server, and outputs to stdout. At the moment, I run this script on the hour from cron, and redirect the output to a file, like this:

> ./mybackupscript > ~/backups/mybackupfile

Sometimes the backup will fail (for example, the network connection is down, or the remote server times out) - this means the stdout content is either incomplete, or missing. The utility is well behaved - when this happens, it exits with a non-zero exit code. However, the backup file is at that point still empty or incomplete. I would prefer that it retain its original contents (from the last successful run of my script).

What is the most appropriately "Unix-y" way of handling this issue, to make the backup more robust? Should I output to a temporary file, then copy it over the final file only if the backup works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I output to a temporary file, then copy it over the final file only if the backup works?

Not copy but rename.

But this is impossible for the backup script if it writes to `stdout`. It cannot even prevent the empty file from being created as that has already happened when the script starts. This must be done from the outside.

```
if ./script.sh >backup.tmp; then
  mv backup.tmp backup
else
  rm backup.tmp
fi
```

Comment: Great, don't know how I missed something so obvious. Thanks. Marking this one correct as you've got a longer explanation (thanks, though, Stéphane!)

Comment: @AndrewFerrier That's why we call it "accepted answer" not "correct answer". :-)

Comment: Thinking about it, I would also add: `|| rm backup.tmp` to clean up the temporary file. Does that seem reasonable or is there unforeseen danger there?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier No. It's rather strange that none of us had this idea by himself.

Comment: If you like `./script.sh > backup.tmp && cp backup.tmp backup ; rm backup.tmp`

Comment: @Costas `cp`...?

Comment: Yes, because `; rm backup.tmp` and probably `cp` need `-f` or `--remove-destination` option.

Comment: Additionally OP can use `-b` or `--backup=[CONTROL]`

Comment: @Costas And why is `backup.tmp && cp backup.tmp backup ; rm backup.tmp` better than `backup.tmp && mv backup.tmp backup || rm backup.tmp`? `mv` can fail but that should not be a problem here.

Comment: Sorry, It is not better, just other way with the same result but as for me `cp` have more options instead of `mv`

Comment: @Costas `mv` doesn't need those options (if it's within the same filesystem).